# Install PostgreSQL on a Mac With Homebrew and Lunchy issues(mac os)

Tags: python, macos, postgresql, homebrew

Hi I want to install the postgresql database in the terminal with Homebrew.
I followed the instruction as showed the following link:

https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-a-mac-with-homebrew-and-lunchy/

I has went to Step 6: Start/Stop Postgres, but there is error:
after I run the command:mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents

There is error:mkdir: /Users/tianke0711/Library/LaunchAgents: Not a directory, and is showed as figure.

[image: error displayed]

I want to say I am not good at Unix command. Also I want to ask what's the meaning -p. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `-p` creates the directory and its parents only if they don’t exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just delete the -p in this command.
 I mean: mkdir ~/Library/LaunchAgents.
It works, I am not sure the meaning of -p, if someone know this, please tell me! Thanks every one!